# Google Spreadsheet to Google form - Error when creating answer key

Tags: google-apps-script

```
function getDataFromGoogleSheets() {
  const correctColor = "#ff0000"; // Please set this for your actual situation.

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName('test1');
  const range = sheet.getDataRange();
  const ar = range.getDisplayValues();
  const choices = ar[0].map((_, col) => ar.map((row) => row[col])).map(([h, ...v]) => [h, v]);
  const correct = range.getTextStyles().reduce((ar, r, i) => {
    r.forEach((c, j) => {
      if (c.getForegroundColorObject().asRgbColor().asHexString() == correctColor) {
        ar.push([i - 1, j]);
      }
    });
    return ar;
  }, []);
  //Logger.log(correct);
  return { choices, correct };
}

function myFunction1() {
  const { choices, correct } = getDataFromGoogleSheets();
  const form = FormApp.create('New Form');
  form.setIsQuiz(true);
  choices.forEach(([h, v], j) => {
    const q = form.addMultipleChoiceItem().setTitle(h).showOtherOption(true);
    const cv = v.map((e, i) => q.createChoice(e, correct[j][0] == i ? true : false));
    q.setChoices(cv);
  });
}
```

1. Two Questions

   [image]
2. Result (2- perfect)

   [image]
3. Three Questions

   [image]
4. Result (2- That's weird)

   [image]
5. Four Questions

   [image]
6. Result (2-That's weird)

   [image]
7. The previous answer has made the work extremely fast.
   Finally, when creating many problems, an error occurs and the question is posted again.
8. The errors are as follows.
   There are no errors in the two questions.
   When creating more than two questions, an error occurs in the correct answer key.
9. Thank you to Tanaike for helping with the above code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your current issue, how about the following modification? Please modify your `getDataFromGoogleSheets()` as follows.

#### From:

```
return { choices, correct };
```

#### To:

```
return { choices, correct: correct.sort((a, b) => a[1] > b[1] ? 1 : -1) };
```

#### Reference:

- [sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

Comment: Thank you, Tanaike
It works perfectly well.